# Insert Widget into pure HTML-code

Tags: gwt, web-applications, servlets

Since the pages I am going to display contain a lot of text, which I want to pre-format in their own text-files, I do the following:

```
execute: onModuleLoad()
         - make an Async call to the server and load 
           the text files which are html-formatted
```

The code looks like this:

```
homeAsync.load(new AsyncCallback<String>() {
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    contentHome.add(new HTML("<h1>FAIL</h1>something went wrong"));
    caught.printStackTrace();
  }

  public void onSuccess(String result) {
    contentHome.getElement().setId("inner");
    contentHome.add(new HTML(result));
    //RootPanel.get("content").add(new HTML(result));
  }
});
```

Now.. inside those text-files are some customized tags:

```
<!graph>
```

which I want to replace with some GWT widgets. My problem is, that I just don't know how I could accomplish that easily.

I could do a work around like:

```
- load text part 1 (async call)
- insert graph for part 1
- load text part 2 (asynca call)
- insert foobar
- and so on ..
```

I don't even know if this would work but to be honest.. that's simply too ugly ^^

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: worked with ui binder?

Comment: no I think that doesn't have anything to do with my issue ^^

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the `part1` and `part2` two makes things much clear.

Yes you can render all the `HTML` content to the `widget` (But in a Safe way,Yes Talking about [SafeHtml](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml)).

And avoid two `RPC` calls to fetch the strings from DB.If you know `part1` and `part2` load the string at a time (with an Identifier and split it on `client side`).

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTMLPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html) as a template.

An example:

```
String html = "<div id='one' style='border:3px dotted blue;'></div>"
    + "<div id='two' style='border:3px dotted green;'></div>";
HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel(html);
panel.setSize("200px", "120px");
panel.addStyleName("demo-panel");
panel.add(new Button("Do Nothing"), "one");
panel.add(new TextBox(), "two");
RootPanel.get("demo").add(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods also:

```
Label w = new Label();
w.getElement().setInnerHTML(html);
w.getElement().setInnerSafeHtml(safeHtml);
```